# getChanges Sharepoint rest API

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint 2013 REST api to find out the incremental changes that have happened in the root site. My request is like below:

```
headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token, "accept": "application/json", "odata": "verbose"}

headers["content-type"] = "application/json;odata=verbose"
body = { 'query': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' },'Web': True, 'Update': True, 'Add': True,
   'ChangeTokenStart':{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.ChangeToken'}, 
   'StringValue': '1;1;5b9752ee-f410-4cc6-9ab6-eb18c2ad802f;636252579049500000;89866182'}
     }
}
```

In response I am getting lot of changerequest objects. One of them is as below:

```
{
            'odata.type': 'SP.ChangeWeb',
            'ChangeToken': {
                'StringValue': '1;1;5b9752ee-f410-4cc6-9ab6-eb18c2ad802f;636252779425600000;89976872'
            },
            'WebId': '6e21eadd-4155-494d-9a8e-1046865bdd4b',
            'ChangeType': 2,
            'odata.id': 'https://<site url>/_api/SP.ChangeWeb87f1a9c6-937b-4507-973d-fc2d1b949aed',
            'SiteId': '5b9752ee-f410-4cc6-9ab6-eb18c2ad802f',
            'odata.editLink': 'SP.ChangeWeb87f1a9c6-937b-4507-973d-fc2d1b949aed',
            'Time': '2017-03-16T16:19:02.56Z'
```

Can somebody help me understand the response? I am facing difficulty to find out the path where the change happened. Also, would this getchanges API capture changes that has happened in subsites within the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Lists and Libraries at the end of the day are the same thing. You can get the list title from odata.editLink by stripping off the last segment (Items(1)) in the above case. If you call that path it'll give you the details of the list versus the item/file that was modified. If you want the user's details call /_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/Items(EditorId). If you want the path to the item/file call odata.editlink and the serverrelativeurl parameter returned will have the path to it and title will have the title of the item/file.

Comment: Thanks Maarten :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the ChangeType is the main piece of information you need which is an enumerable. You can look up the friendly names for the numbers here: [ChangeType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changetype.aspx)

So in that case, that looks like an update to the settings of the SPWeb with a guid of '6e21eadd-4155-494d-9a8e-1046865bdd4b'

You may also want to look at using the $expand operator in your REST query to get additional fields back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but what I am failing to understand is where can I get the information regarding the name of the object where the actual change has happened i.e., if the change is inside a list, then how can i retrieve it's name and other details from the response?

Comment: Your query is only requesting changes to a web, not a list which is why you're not seeing more information. Change 'Web':True to 'List':True to get list changes :)

Then you'll see for the details you'll see the ChangeType and the ObjectsChanged (with a Web query the object changed can only ever be Web or Navigation). It won't give you a complete breakout however of what the full change was, just what it impacted like a Field, or a ContentType. But not what field, or what contenttype and no before and after comparison.